# Checking If User Has a Role with Specific Claim

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-identity

I can't figure out the proper, and most efficient way, of doing this. I feel dates and versions are important in case things change in the future (seems to happen a lot as I'm searching for the answer).

Using `Visual Studio 2017` v15.5.5, I started a new MVC ASP.NET Web Application (.Net Framework, not CORE) with Individual Accounts. I upgraded all the packages. Currently using `EntityFramework` v6.2.0 and `Identity` v2.2.1.

**What I have Done**

I manually implemented my own version of `RoleClaims`. I have a `class` which defines `RoleClaims` and another `class` which defines all the application's `Claims`. In the application, `Claims` are used to define what can be done. For example, a `Claim` can be `View Users` or `Edit Users` or even `Delete Users`.

**Goal**

Based on a given `IdentityUser`, and a `Claim` name, I want to know does the user have that `Claim`?

**Classes**

```
public class RoleClaim {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    public IdentityRole Role { get; set; }
    public int ClaimId { get; set; }
    public Claim Claim { get; set; }
}

public class Claim {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ClaimType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RoleClaim> RoleClaims { get; set; }
}
```

**A little more context**

I prefer to have an answer in `Linq` expressions, but `Linq` queries are fine too.

Also, I'm doing all this logic in a custom `AuthorizeAttribute`, based on the following, so there's a good chance I might be doing other things wrong. =) Feel free to comment on it.

- [Writing your own custom ASP.Net MVC [Authorize] attributes](http://dougrathbone.com/blog/2011/07/24/writing-your-own-custom-aspnet-mvc-authorize-attributes)
- [System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute.cs](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs)

**ClaimsAuthorizationAttribute**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class ClaimsAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute {
    private static readonly string[] _emptyArray = new string[0];
    private string _claims;
    private string[] _claimsSplit = _emptyArray;

    public string Claims {
        get => _claims ?? string.Empty;
        set {
            _claims = value;
            _claimsSplit = SplitString(value);
        }
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
        if (filterContext == null) {
            throw new ArgumentException("filterContext");
        }

        if (AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext)) {
            // allowed... research anything else needed to be done
        } else {
            HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) {
        if (httpContext == null) {
            throw new ArgumentException("httpContext");
        }

        var user = httpContext.User;
        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            return false;
        }

        /*
         * _claimsSplit contains all allowed Claims with access
         * 
         * Based on the list of Claims, check if any of the Roles 
         * the user is a member of has at least the same Claim
         * 
         * OR
         * 
         * Based on the users' Roles, check if any of those 
         * roles has at least one of the claims that were passed in
         * 
         * 
         * 
         * Should I check for any or should it be ALL Claims 
         * passed in? or should I pass another variable (bool) 
         * allowing the ability to decide if it should be 
         * at least 1 or all?
        */

        return true;
    }

    internal static string[] SplitString(string original) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(original)) {
            return _emptyArray;
        }

        var split = from piece in original.Split(',')
                    let trimmed = piece.Trim()
                    where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(trimmed)
                    select trimmed;
        return split.ToArray();
    }
}
```

**Summary**

I need help figuring out an efficient way to check if a `User` has a `Claim` though their `Roles`.

**Solution**

For anyone interested, thanks to [Stephen Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke) I was able to create the solution. Anyone interested can view my version of [ClaimsAuthorizationAttribute.cs](https://gist.github.com/RoLYroLLs/af072e3ae9b875f1c3b6a0efd731950e).

Comment: What is not working with your code?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Trying to write the `Linq` expression to check if a `User` has a `Claim` through their `Roles`

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your relationships, but you would need to get a collection of the users roles, get all `RoleClaim ` that contain any of those roles where the `RoleClaim.Claim.Name` matches. Seems fairly inefficient to be doing that on every request.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm still learning `Linq` and still researching how to do it. I too believe it's inefficient, but what other options would you suggest?

Comment: Not sure (still trying to understand why you have your `Claim` and `RoleClaim` classes)

Comment: @StephenMuecke A `User` has `Roles` and a `Role` had `Claims`. The relationship between `Role` and `Claim` is `RoleClaim`. Let me know if still not clear. I'll try to add some data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164942/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-rolyrolls).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have the `User` (e.g. `var User = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == user.Identity.Name)`, you can first get the collection of Role ID's for the User

```
var roleIds = User.Roles.Select(x => x.Id);
```

Then get the names of all the claims having one of those Role ID's

```
var claims = db.RoleClaims.Where(x => roleIds.Contains(x => x.RoleId)).Select(x => x.Claim.Name);
```

And finally test if there are any matches

```
if (claims.Any(x => _claimsSplit.Contains(x)))
```

However, since this is going to be call on each request, you should consider caching the results in `MemoryCache` (assuming `RoleClaim` are not going to change often). One method would be to have a `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>` where the key is the `RoleId` and the value is the collection of `Claim` names.

You could either populate the `Dictionary` on start-up with all values, or just add to it as required. The psuedo code would be something like

```
private const string key = "RoleClaims"

private bool HasClaim(string[] requiredClaims)
{
    // Check the cache
    Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> roleClaims = Cache.Get(key)
    if (roleClaims == null)
    {
        roleClaims = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>();
        Cache.Set(key, roleClaims, 240);
    }
    foreach (var role in roleIds)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> claims;
        if (roleClaims.ContainsKey(role))
        {
            claims = roleClaims[role];
        }
        else
        {
            claims = db.RoleClaims.Where(roleIds == role).Select(x => x.Claim.Name);
            roleClaims.Add(role, claims)
        }
        if (claims.Any(x => requiredClaims.Contains(x)))
        {
            return true // exit
        }
    }
return false;
}
```

and call it the `AuthorizeCore()` using

```
return HasClaim(_claimsSplit);
```

You will just need to ensure that the cache is invalidated when an existing `RoleClaim`is modified or a new one added so that your not working with 'stale' data.

Note the `Cache` class above is

```
public static class Cache
{
    public static object Get(string key)
    {
        return MemoryCache.Default[key];
    }
    public static void Set(string key, object data, int duration = 30)
    {
        CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
        policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(duration);
        MemoryCache.Default.Add(new CacheItem(key, data), policy);
    }
    public static void Invalidate(string key)
    {
        MemoryCache.Default.Remove(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! 2 questions come to mind: 1) Since I have to hit the DB for every request just to get the `RoleIds`, should I `Cache` this too? or would that be too inefficient when too many users are logged in and stick with db access? What do you suggest? 2) The application will have a set number of `Claims`, that will only change if the site is redesigned, maybe 50 or 60, and 4 `Roles`. The `SysAdmin` role with have claim to all while other roles may have 2-40. I plan on using `Redis Cache` and I hear it's better to have smaller bits of data per `CacheItem`. Any suggestions?

Comment: My gut feeling says to inverse and have the `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>` where the key is the `ClaimName` and the value is the collection of `RoleIds`

Comment: Point 1 - But that is what the purpose of the `HasClaim()` method is. It first checks if the cached Dictionary exists, and that it contains a key for the RoleId. If it does it just reads the value from the Dictionary (i.e. no database call). If it dos not exist, then get the data from the db and add it to the `Dictionary` to subsequent request do not call the db.

Comment: But looking at the code I gave, I see I did not pass in the `roleIds` to the method (I'll update that a bit later). Point 2 - Yes that would probably work as well.

Comment: For Point1, I meant to Cache the `RoleIds` of the `User`. Unless I'm not understanding part of the code, where is it caching the `User`'s `RoleIds`?

Comment: Cool, I'll await your update, however, I have completely disassembled your code and rewrote it a bit. =) I don't know it's it's efficient. Would you mind looking at it? If so, how do you want to post it? Thanks!

Comment: OK (I misunderstood your comment). Yes, that could be cached as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165004/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-rolyrolls).